# Parsing YAML file with perl. How to access and parse different yaml objects.

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm looking for some help parsing a YAML document.  Specifically i'm not sure host to print out/access the "volumes" elements.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use YAML::Tiny;


# Open the config
$yaml = YAML::Tiny->read( 'file.yml' );

# Reading properties
my $root = $yaml->[0]->{rootproperty};
my $one  = $yaml->[0]->{physical_interfaces}->{e0a};
my $Foo  = $yaml->[0]->{physical_interfaces}->{e0b};
print "$root\n";
print "$one\n";
print "$volume1\n";
```

my yaml file looks like this: file.yaml

```
---
    rootproperty: netapp1
    is_netapp: Yes
    netapp_mode: 7mode
    is_metro_cluster: Yes
    is_vseries: Yes
    is_flexcache_origin: No
    snapmirror:
      enabled: Yes
      destination: Yes
      lag_threshold: 2300
    physical_interfaces:
      e0a: netapp1-e0
      e0b: netapp1-e1
      mgt: netapp1-mgt
    volumes:
      - volume: vol1
        reserve: 50
        sched: 6 42 0
      - volume: vol2
        reserve: 20
        sched: 0 3 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you seem to have the right idea already. In the same way as you can access the `rootproperty` field with

```
my $root = $yaml->[0]{rootproperty}
```

you can access the `volumes` array with

```
my $volumes = $yaml->[0]{volumes}
```

`$volumes` is now a reference to an array of volume hashes. You could print these out, for instance, using

```
for my $vol (@$volumes) {
  print $vol->{volume}, "\n";
  print $vol->{reserve}, "\n";
  print $vol->{sched}, "\n";
  print "\n";
}
```

With the data you show, this will produce the output

```
vol1
50
6 42 0

vol2
20
0 3 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Borodin!